# Increase Amperage With Capacitors without any change in voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor, amperage

I want to know how to increase the current/amperage without changing the amount of 
voltage. I found this  formula:
**I (t) = 
Vs/R * e^-t/RC**

from this website:http://www.ehow.com/how_8780713_increase-amperage-capacitors-diodes.html

but i don't unserstand how **t** is found, because it set to: **t  = 3 microseconds** how did they calculate that **t** is 3 microseconds? can anyone give me sample and how  (e^-2) = 0.8, becouse i'm getting it to be: **0.13533528323**

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! As written, your question is vague and difficult to answer. You say you want to "increase the current", but what current are you talking about? And what voltage? Can you please clarify your question, and possibly the title?

Comment: Off cource you can get more current from a bigger capacitor, but after this you have "something" to replenish with the same power or energy. Btw the formula that you mention is valid for a charging up to 63% and not for 99%

Comment: I mean 5v, 1.2 where i Want 5v output with much more current then 1.2 like 2 or 3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a lot of information on eHow is of very low quality. The eHow article defines *"t is the elapsed time since the power supply was turned on"*

If you connect a source of electricity with a fixed voltage (constant voltage supply) to a capacitor through a resistor, the capacitor will charge, the current that flows will be initially large but will decrease over time. The formula describes that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foJe0i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$I = \frac{V}{R}e^{-t/RC} $$

Note that the exponent of \$e\$ is \$\frac{-t}{RC}\$

See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html

---

> **I want to know how to increase the current/amperage without changing the amount of voltage.**

A capacitor can act as a short-term store of energy that can be released in a short burst over a small amount of time if your load occasionally requires more power than your power supply can deliver.

A capacitor cannot make a 12V DC 1A power supply into a 12V DC 2A power supply.

Amperage in the most basic sense, is what controls the amount of work that can be done from a constant voltage.
The circuit that would need to be added to the capacitor would be a resistor with ohm value of 2000 connected to a Darlington pair of transistors.

Amperage can also be increased through the usage of magnets. (Wink)

Comment: Based on RedGrittyBrick's answer, you could try to decrease the resistance R1 in the circuit. The lower that is, the higher your peak current will be.

Comment: Let say i have input 5v, 1.2a or 1.5 how do i increase the current to 2.5 or 3+ without changing the voltage ?  What options do i have ?? And how is it done??

Comment: @user1022734: In general: reduce the impedance of the load. In this case, increase C.

Comment: I understand that t is defined as " the elapsed time since the power supply was turned on" but why 3 microseconds why not 5, 10, 60 microseconds? What the math behind that and how do i know the right amount of resistor that i'm connecting to the capacitor?? Why is it set to 300 ohm ?

Comment: @user1022734: The 3 is just an example. It's of no practical use. There is no single "right" value for the resistor. It depends on what you really want to do. The article you linked to is not a solution to any practical problem it is an academic exercise. See amended answer.

Comment: Thanks i understand it now, let me ask like that. How Can i turn 12v DC 1a to 12v DC 2a what options do i have ?? And how

Comment: @user1022734: Only by selling your 1A supply on eBay and using the money to buy a 2A supply. It isn't possible to magic energy out of nothing, a 12V 2A supply provides twice as much energy per second - a 12V 1A supply simply cannot provide that much energy per second.

Comment: So i have only 2 options, either buy new power supply or Build my own..hmm it worth making by myself to learn